# Build table with php and sql

Tags: php, sql

I want to use prepared statement which works fine if it's just one row, but when I want to build a table it only shows the first row. I'm missing something simple somewhere, but I've tried all sorts of things which just broke.

```
<?php 
        $dbh = dbh_get();
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM products
            WHERE prod_id >6
            ORDER BY prod_id';
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $r = $stmt->fetch();

print '
    <tr>
        <td>' . $r['login_id'] . '</td>
        <td>' . $r['outlet_code'] . '</td>
        <td>' . $r['user_name'] . '</td>
        <td>' . $r['user_role'] . '</td>
        <td>' . $r['last_login'] . '</td>
        <td>' . $r['user_id'] . '</td>
    </tr>' . "\n";
dbh_free($dbh);
?>
```

Unsure if it's the php or the sql which is the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop on the results of `$stmt->fetch()` as it will return one row per call:

```
while ($r = $stmt->fetch()) {
    print '
    <tr>
        <td>' . $r['login_id'] . '</td>
        <td>' . $r['outlet_code'] . '</td>
        <td>' . $r['user_name'] . '</td>
        <td>' . $r['user_role'] . '</td>
        <td>' . $r['last_login'] . '</td>
        <td>' . $r['user_id'] . '</td>
    </tr>' . "\n";
}
```